# Bulk upload and download using OCI Java SDK

Tags: oracle-call-interface, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I've gone through example here for single file upload and download. 
https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/UploadObjectExample.java
However, I'm not finding any java OCI API for bulk upload/download of multiple files. I know this is possible if we use OCI CLI, but the requirement here is using Java APIs. Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in OCI API for bulk uploading/downloading files. You would need to do something similar to the example you linked to above, in a loop, for all the files you need to upload/download.

Comment: Thanks @Joe,  I'm zipping all the files and uploading it as of now, IO operations in loop would be a performance overhead.

Comment: "IO operations in loop would be a performance overhead" -- ok, but this is also how the OCI CLI does what you are asking for support for. So doing these operations in a loop as I described would give you parity with the feature and its performance of this in the CLI

Comment: Ahh...I dint know OCI CLI internally works in a loop for Bulk -uploads. Thanks @Joe, I'll re-evaluate our strategy of uploads/downloads.